# PyGtk: pass most recent data to module when button clicked?

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm wondering how to update the variable being sent through the PyGtk expression `button.connect("clicked", funct, data)`. I want my function to receive the most recent data when the button is clicked, not the data that existed at the time `button.connect()` was called.

A very similar question was answered at http://mailman.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2006-October/013018.html but did not involve the use of seperate python files, as my question does.

Specifically, my code has two python files, `main.py` and `utils.py`, and the function I want to call lies in `utils.py`. The code works as desired if I put the `on_clicked` function inside `main.py`, where the `data` variable is defined, but I don't want to do that, as it interferes with modularisation.

`utils.py` contains some function with an argument:

```
def on_click(button, data):
    print(data)
```

`main.py` calls this function through the `button.connect()` expression:

```
import utils

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

data = "1"

win = Gtk.Window()
button = Gtk.Button(label="call the on_click function")
button.connect("clicked", utils.on_click, data)
win.add(button)

data = "2"

win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

When `data` is updated, `on_clicked` is still operating with the old `data`; i.e. `1` is being printed. I tried simply calling `button.connect("clicked", utils.on_click, data)` again after the `data` update, but that seems to cause its own problems and isn't very elegant - `connect()` should only have to be called once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing one object and then assign data to another one. The callback only knows about the first object.

There are some approaches but i'll give a simple example, where you create a class with setter/getter and then you will be able to change the value of a property in the object instance the callback knows about:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

class UserData:
    def __init__(self, data_value):
        self.data = data_value;

    def setData(self, new_value):
        self.data = new_value

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

def on_click(button, data):
    print(data.getData())

data = UserData("1")

win = Gtk.Window()
button = Gtk.Button(label="call the on_click function")
button.connect("clicked", on_click, data)
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.add(button)

data.setData("2") 

win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps me. I didn't realise that I was even passing an object, but I'm quite new to python. Thanks again.